# Python Tkinter replace button onclick with entry that after pressed enter will turn back to button with entry input

Tags: python, tkinter, events, overlap

I'm trying to have a tkinter button, that when clicked, is ***replaced*** with an `tk.Entry()`, and after pressing `enter` in the entry, the entry is replaced with a ***new*** button that has the text of the entry ( `entry.get()` )...

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

def func(neww):
    b = tk.Button(root, text=neww, command=onclick)
    b.grid(row=0, column=0)

def onclick():
    e = tk.Entry(root)
    e.grid(row=0, column=0)
    e.bind('<Return>', func(e.get()))

b = tk.Button(root, text='clickme', command=onclick)
b.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I can't post a photo for some reason, but the result is the entries and buttoons overlap, 
as well as the new button being created `OnFocus` instead of when there is a `Return` event. 
These are two seperate issues with the code, and I'd really appreciate some help with both :)

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked, you need to *hide* the button and create the entry box.

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, update the text of the hidden button, destroy the entry box and then show back the button.

```py
def func(evt):
    # update button text
    b.config(text=evt.widget.get())
    # remove the entry box
    evt.widget.destroy()
    # show back the button
    b.grid(row=0, column=0)

def onclick():
    # hide the button
    b.grid_forget()
    # show the entry box
    e = tk.Entry(root)
    e.grid(row=0, column=0)
    e.bind('<Return>', func)
    e.focus_set()
```